# Can Q destroy its own omnipotent powers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

If Q are omnipotent and can do absolutely anything, are they also capable of destroing their own omnipotent powers and become... average species? Is there any in-universe, canon example or explanation for this (I'm not talking about suicide or murder)?

Could this (completely destroying one's own omnipotent powers) be a solution to [Amanda Rogers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Amanda_Rogers) in "[True Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/True_Q_%28episode%29)" episode? If she'd do that, she would stop being any "problem" to Q continuum and she could follow her Starfleet career, she was always dreaming about.

Comment: Q Junior was turned into a normal human, and was almost sentenced to lose Q-hood forever. Q lose their powers all the time.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I think the question is asking if a Q could destroy their own powers, not if their powers can be stripped by the other Q.

Comment: @tarchibald Exactly -- as in given example with Amanda Rogers.

Comment: If god is omnipotent can S/He make a rock so big she can't move it? Discuss.

Comment: @Lexible - Yes they can. No wait, no they can't. * head explodes *

Comment: @Lexible I know this dilema / paradox. My question is actually a modified version of it. I didn't mention it in the question to avoid making it sounding more like philosophical than in-Trek one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes (probably).**

In TNG : [Q, Who?](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/142.txt) Q offers to remove his own powers and serve as guide to the Enteprise crew.

> **Q :** *Yes, more and more I realize that here -- here is where I want to be. Think of the advantages. Now, I neither expect nor require
>   **if necessary**, although I can't imagine why, **I will renounce my powers
>   and become as weak and incompetent as all of you.***

Having said that, perhaps we should perhaps take a statement from someone whose various nicknames include the "***God of lies***" (DS9: Q-Less) at less than face value, nor is it clear by what process this *renouncing* would take.

---

With regard to Amanda Rogers, it's clear that although her parents had also chosen to become human, their offspring still had Q-like powers. It's reasonable to assume that the Q would be less than happy with the idea of Amanda sprinkling her god-like DNA into the human genepool, even if she personally offered to renounce her powers.

Comment: This answers the general question (thanks). I imagine, we will never know, why Amanda wasn't able to pick this solution?

Comment: @trejder - Because she still had Q genes. Becoming human doesn't seem to stop your children having Q powers.

Comment: @Richard So the powers of the Q don't include altering genetics?

Comment: @KSmarts - I didn't write the show. Don't blame me :-)

Comment: Consider the DNA of the Q to contain epigenetic aspects which allow them to access the "technology" of the Q even if a particular individual chooses to renounce their personal access to that technology. This access may not be known to an individual if they never knew it existed but if someone were to possess the ability and be taught how to access it, then they would go from being a mere human to a fully fledged Q once they harnessed the ability. It is possible there are other Q-humans who live and die as humans and are none the wiser for their limited human experience.

Comment: Let's not forget Quinn from Voyager, a Q who attempts (and fails) to commit suicide.  Later, the Q continuum grants him mortality, and he promptly (and successfully) kills himself.

Comment: @MartianInvader - I thought about that but having your powers stripped is a different prospect than removing your own powers.

Comment: @Richard Again, exactly. My question asks precisely about destroying your own (as Q) Q powers. Nothing about being expelled or having them removed by other Q or any other force.

Comment: @thaddeus so basically the ancient gene in Stargate?

Comment: I think the 'Quinn' thing directly contradicts this. If Quinn 'could' remove his own powers he could have killed himself in countless ways, the fact he need the continuum to do it suggests that it takes more than 1 Q to do it (The quote about him 'relinquishing his power' in TNG, sounds like he would ask the continuum to to it for him)

Comment: @Matt - He's prevented from doing so by his fellow Q. The principle seems to be that the only thing more powerful than a Q is two Q.